# firefox error console inside Web Developer

Tags: firefox, console

Is there a way to rename or remove a menu in Firefox. My Error Console is hidden under the Web Developer Menu and I want it to be under the Tools instead. Please see screengrab: http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/5720/firefoxpv.jpg

THank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing this plugin and see if it enables what you are trying to do.

[Firefox Menu Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/menu-editor)

Comment: I'm using this add-on and there is in fact an entry in Menu Editor available with 'Console', not within WebDeveloper entry, but standalone built-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install [Toolbar Buttons](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/toolbar-buttons/) and you'll have additional set of buttons that you can put in various places. Right click e.g. on 'Refresh' button, select 'customize' and here you go. Console is a red button with exclamation mark.